# Unable to bind the JSF Managed Bean with the rendered view

Tags: jsf

I am working on a Java web application using JSF. I have a managed bean which is session scoped. This bean is utilized in one of the jsp in the application. It seems like the bean is not instantiated when the page is rendered. However, I am able to see the constructor being invoked for the managed bean when the 'commandButton' is clicked.

The property binding is done using the value attribute in 'h:inputText' tag. The action attribute of the 'h:commandButton' is bound to one of the method in the Managed Bean.

The Bean class

```
public class EventController implements Serializable{
private String eventName;
private String eventVenue;

//Getters, Setter & No Arg Constructor


public String proceed(){
   //Implementation for proceed
}

}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>eventController</managedBean>
   <managed-bean-class>com.eventapp.eventController</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

event.jsp

```
<tr>
  <td>
       <label>event Name:</label>     
  </td>
  <td>
       <h:inputText value="#{eventContoller.eventName}">
  </td>
<tr>

<tr>
  <td>
       <label>event Venue:</label>     
  </td>
  <td>
       <h:inputText value="#{eventContoller.eventVenue}">
  </td>
<tr>

<tr>
  <td>
       <h:commandButton action="#{eventController.proceed}" value="Continue" />
  </td>
<tr>
```

I expect to see blank value in the text field but I am seeing '#{eventContoller.eventName}'.

Comment: jsp? In jsf 2.2...Sure? That has loooong been deprecated in jsf in favour of facelets. And tags are for where a problem is, this is jsf and not something jsf-2.2 specific, so addung version info in your question and using the basic jsf tag is the better thing to do

Comment: And you actually have no quotes around the atributes of the jsf tags? And no `h:form` and the 'view-source' on the client shows html and not jsf tags? And you know you canse annotations instead of xml for declaring managedbeans?

Comment: This is just the part of my client code. I do have <h:form> in my original code.I have corrected the code by putting quotes on the jsf tags  still not seeing what is expected. And yes, I am aware of the annotations for configuring the managed bean.  The thing I observe is that the session bean(eventController) is loaded only when I click the Continue button. It should be loaded on page load.

Comment: Please read [mcve].... always create one, remove the td, tr etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your bean has the wrong name in JSP: eventContoller. You defined: eventController. See

```
 <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>eventController</managedBean>
   <managed-bean-class>com.eventapp.eventController</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: By 'wrong name', do you mean the value in the tag '<managed-bean-name>'? If you mean '<managed-bean-class>' then my bad. It was a typo in adding the question. Checked in the code and it is <managed-bean-class>com.eventapp.EventController</managed-bean-class>

Comment: i wanted to say that you miss a letter "r"  in your controller name: you have defined  as eventController (see the 'r") and used as eventContoller (no 'r');

Comment: Yes, corrected the typo. Still seeing the same result : '#{eventcontroller.eventName}' in the text field.

Comment: Let me see the erro log. Put here

Comment: There were no errors being thrown. Whenever I change the value of input text, the respective setters of the configured beans should be called. But I don't see that being called. Also, I have explicitly defined the constructor of the bean and it looks like it is invoked only when I click the 'Continue' button. If I am not wrong, the constructor should be invoked on page load.

Comment: What's JSF version you are using ?

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the <h:commandButton> end tag. However the issue here seems to be that the bean is initialized only when the command button is clicked. It should be initialized when the page is loaded since it is Session scoped.